# Android Cordova HTML5 Canvas OnTouch Wrong

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, canvas

I set my html5 canvas to fit my screen width like this:

```
canvas.width = screenWidth;
canvas.height = screenHeight;
```

But I when I do:

```
canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", function(e) {
    var x = e.touches[0].screenX;
    var y = e.touches[0].screenY;
    console.log(x.toString() + "X");
});
```

x and y are always very small, why is this and how could I fix it?

EDIT:

I want to be accurate in my touch events since I am making a game that will rely on them.

Answer (score 0):

Which values are you obtaining?
Did you you have on your index.html?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />
```

The browser on a mobile device runs with a pixel-density different from 1, unlike the computers.
For example, if the pixel-density is 2, expect to see your values 2 times smaller.
Try to run it on your desktop Chrome, with the emulation activated (developer tools->emulation).
Select the same device as you are testing, and compare the values.

Comment: Hi code ranger, thx for the suggestion. I will try it out soon. I still haven't gotten this working so for now I'm just creating a touch multiplier and multiplying the touches to fill the screen

Comment: That is strange. I have created several times canvas that work both on the desktop as well as on mobile, and I don't have to multiply the numbers.
I post more information, perhaps I can help, but with the information that you are providing i's not enough to solve the problem.